# how to query file field in parse javascript

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I have 10 file fields in my UserAccount in parse table say file1. file2, file3 and son on. I want to query the UserAccount Table so its only fetch those records which has at least 1 file available. If all fields are empty for particular USerAccount then it should not be in the result.

Want a javascript parse query that do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do this is (sadly, I wish there was a better way) to combine disjunctive queries with Parse.Query.or().

In your case, one query per file column, like this:

```
var queryFile1 = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
queryFile1.exists("file1");

var queryFile2 = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
queryFile2.exists("file2");

// and so on, then
Parse.Query.or([queryFile1, queryFile2, ...]).then(function(results) {
    // results will be an array of users that have any one of file1,2,3 defined
});
```

This can be made a little more terse using underscore.js...

```
var _ = require('underscore');

var columns = ["file1", "file2", ...  ];
var queries = _.map(columns, function(column) {
    return new Parse.Query(Parse.User).exists(column);
});
Parse.Query.or(queries).then(...
```